# Thrift in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, thrift

I have a .m and .h file that generated with Thrift for objective-c based on this link :

```
http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageObjectiveC
```

but there are a lot of error in .m files like :

```
1.  error: duplicate interface definition for class 

2.  reimplementation of class 'bitlit_thrift_detect_cover_args'

3.  use of undeclared identifier '__claim_id'; did you mean 'claim_id'?

4.  use of undeclared identifier '__claim_id_isset'

5.  reference to local variable 'claim_id' declared in enclosing context

6.  error: use of undeclared identifier '__claim_id_isset'
__claim_id_isset = YES;


.....


7.  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
```

would you please give me some hints, what is the problem?, is the error related to the xcode setting? my xCode Version is Version 4.6.1

Thanks in advance!

Here is the errors Picture:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to have a look at the IDL file. Is that possible?

Comment: @JensG thanks for your reply, It was a bug in the objective-c thrift generator: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1790